# How to open a file in Jsp using filepath

Tags: java, struts1, struts-1

path in my database and files stored in the server path "workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ex/userfiles" . I want to open the file in jsp page using the file path .Iam using eclipse juno in ubuntu
I tried this code... please help me thanks in advance
 href="filepath"

Comment: You want what? Confuse question, what do you mean with "open"? Show it in the JSP Page, send it to the user, include it in the JSP?

Comment: I want to download the file or when clicks on the link the file should be open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the .jsp files should be inside WebContent folder or one of its children.
If the file, say index.jsp, is inside WebContent folder then the path is: /index.jsp
If the file is in WebContent/SomeFolder then the path is: /SomeFolder/index.jsp